# Проблема с восстановлением БД в UTF8

Tags: windows, postgresql, utf-8, psql

Всем привет,

Ни кто не сталкивался с "не задачкой" такой (под windows):
делаю backup database с компрессией (-Z 8) через pg_dump в кодировке UTF8, формат plain (по умолчанию на сервере - UTF8).
А вот, psql не может ничего сделать для restore - всегда одна ошибка:
"неверная последовательность байт для кодировки "UTF8"
если делать без компрессии - все ok.

под nix* и так и так пашет.